# How does append() work in this code snippet? Confused with a particular variable

Tags: python, function, append

Can someone explain this code to me? 
More specifically, the part about lead.append([sum1 - sum2 , 1]) and print(ans[1],ans[0]).

I do not understand the "1" in "lead.append([sum1 - sum2 , 1])"

I, also, do not understand the "1" and "0" in print(ans[1],ans[0]).

```py
lead = []
sum1 , sum2 = 0 , 0
for i in range(int(input())):
    a1 , a2 = map(int, input().split())
    sum1 += a1
    sum2 += a2
    if sum1>sum2:
        lead.append([sum1 - sum2 , 1])
    else:
        lead.append([sum2 - sum1 , 2])

ans = max(lead)
print(ans[1],ans[0])
```

Thanks.

Comment: `ans[1]` and `ans[0]` both refer to indexes in a list - `ans` is a list, `0` is the first entry, `1` is the second entry

Comment: its the second element of the list you're appending.

Comment: Thanks @Sayse. I did not find what I needed in that list indexing link. But thanks for the help! I appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks to you too @Corsaka, I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lead.append([sum2 - sum1 , 2])
```

This is appending to the list 'lead' the value inside the brackets.

```
[sum2 - sum1, 2] <- inside the brackets
```

The 2 or 1 you are referring to is inside a list itself. So you would be appending these entries to the list.
The code seems to check which of sum1/sum2 is greater and then subtracts the lesser one, adding the corresponding value to the list 'lead'.

The last line, assuming that all items in the list are lists themselves, should print the 2nd value of the sublist, then the 1st value of the sublist.

```
In [18]: lead = [[100, 2], [200, 1], [400, 3]]

In [19]: max(lead)
Out[19]: [400, 3]

In [20]: ans = max(lead)

In [21]: print(ans[1], ans[0])
3 400
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried my best to find similar questions so as not to repeat myself but to no avail. One more question - the max() function.Q1. ans here is a list right? Q2. when we use max() for sub-lists, will it find the max of the 1st sublist (100,200 and 400 in your case) or the next sublist (2, 1, 3 in your case)? Thanks!

Comment: No problem! I'll try to answer your question as soon as I can, busy at work at the moment!

Comment: Hi @SuperAwesomeCaptainMcFluffyPa Okay, so in the example I have given, it will first look for a max value in the first entry in each sublist, in this case 400. Then, if there are any duplicate values of this, it will search for the highest value of the second entry, in this case there are no others with a value of [400, X] so [400, 3] is chosen. However if [400, 7] existed, this would be the max per the above logic.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I really appreciate your answer. Thanks again HollowA :D